# Key error in dictionary - different structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm getting that classic error on dictionary. I already try all possibilities that I knew but didn't work. It seems the symbol '[' is the cause of the problem.

Basically, what I want to do is change the key name in json. I'm following [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-change-keys-in-dictionary/) and it works fine, however, when I try to use my own json, it doesn't work (see the '[' on my json).

How can I workaround it? 
P.S: I'm getting that json result from an internal system and I cannot change that.

Here is my code and the error I'm getting:

```
import json
line = {'result': [{'end_date': '2020-05-15 05:00:00', 'number': 'CG0239308', 'cmdb_ci.u_alias': 'DNS', 'short_description': 'DNS test ', 'start_date': '2020-05-15 02:00:00'}]}
line2 = json.dumps(line)
result = json.loads(line2)

print ('line result:', json.dumps(result, indent=5))

ini_dict = result

###Changing dictionary key
# printing initial json 
print ("initial 1st dictionary", ini_dict) 

# changing keys of dictionary 
ini_dict['New_Name'] = ini_dict['cmdb_ci.u_alias'] 
del ini_dict['cmdb_ci.u_alias']

# printing final result 
print ("final dictionary", str(ini_dict))
```

Here is the output of the code and the error:

```
line result: {
     "result": [
          {
               "end_date": "2020-05-15 05:00:00",
               "number": "CG0239308",
               "cmdb_ci.u_alias": "DNS",
               "short_description": "DNS test ",
               "start_date": "2020-05-15 02:00:00"
          }
     ]
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\renato\Desktop\dict.py", line 20, in <module>
    ini_dict['New_Name'] = ini_dict['cmdb_ci.u_alias']
KeyError: 'cmdb_ci.u_alias'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your ini_dict object. It is a dictionary with one key value pair which contains a list with one dictionary in it. Presumably this last dictionary is the one you want to change.

Input:

```
ini_dict
```

Output:

```
{'result': [{'end_date': '2020-05-15 05:00:00',
   'number': 'CG0239308',
   'cmdb_ci.u_alias': 'DNS',
   'short_description': 'DNS test ',
   'start_date': '2020-05-15 02:00:00'}]}
```

This may be what you want for line 20.

```
ini_dict['result'][0]['New_Name'] = ini_dict['result'][0]['cmdb_ci.u_alias']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ini_dict['result'][0]['New_Name'] = ini_dict['result'][0]['cmdb_ci.u_alias']
del ini_dict['result'][0]['cmdb_ci.u_alias']
```

Instead of this:

```
ini_dict['New_Name'] = ini_dict['cmdb_ci.u_alias'] 
del ini_dict['cmdb_ci.u_alias']
```

Comment: I have tested all 3 answers and all worked fine!!! Thank you a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary has a nested structure. The only key at the top level is `result`. The value for that key is a list; the first element of that list is another dictionary which has the key you're looking for.

You can pull it out first like so:

```
inner_dict = ini_dict['result'][0]
```

Then you can change the key:

```
inner_dict['New Name'] = inner_dict.pop('cmdb_ci.u_alias')
```

The `pop` method removes *and* returns the value so you don't need a separate call to `del`.